# Read and write through in apache ignite

Tags: ignite

I want to perform read and write through using apache ignite. I know that we have to use "cacheStoreAdapter" interface for it. In these interface we have 3 methods, "Load, write and delete". In write/load methods we have to explicitly write persistent db queries. Is there a way where on cache.put(), it writes to persistent db automatically????

Answer (score 0):

There are two implementations to automatically persist data in db - CacheJdbcPojoStore and CacheJdbcBlobStore.
https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/store/jdbc/CacheJdbcPojoStore.html
https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/cache/store/jdbc/CacheJdbcBlobStore.java

Comment: On cache.put(), is that necessary to write queries explicitly to insert data into db???

Comment: I meant, cant it automatically update the db on cache.put()??

Comment: @Pooja Yes, of course, every cache.put() will automatically write-through to DB.

Comment: yeah thats true, but in write method -  we explicitly have to write the implementation( query of persistance db ) right????

Comment: I wanted to know whether is it possible to do without writing queries explicitly

Comment: @Pooja CacheJdbcPojoStore does not require writing SQL queries explicitly, it uses reflection mechanism. Please take a look at this page https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store#section-cachejdbcpojostore

Comment: `CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory store= new CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory();
       store.setDataSource(dataSource);
CacheConfiguration<String,Person> ordersCacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>(Constants.IGNITE_CACHE_NAME);
ordersCacheCfg.setAtomicityMode(TRANSACTIONAL);
ordersCacheCfg.setCacheStoreFactory(store);
  
ordersCacheCfg.setReadThrough(true);
  
ordersCacheCfg.setWriteThrough(true);
      
Ignite ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(configuration);
IgniteCache<String,Person> cache = Ignite.getOrCreateCache(ordersCacheCfg);
      
    cache.put("First", new Person("Pooja","raikar",1));`

Comment: I have used the above code.... It throws "class org.apache.ignite.transactions.TransactionRollbackException: Transaction has been rolled back:" error

Comment: I have created the table by name "Person" in orient db... I have to get the data from db to cache.

Comment: @Pooja could you please update your post with the stack trace that you got?

Comment: @Pooja by the way, it is recommended to use `CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory.setDataSourceFactory()` instead of `CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory.setDataSource()`

Comment: Failed to execute job [jobId=d5513c19461-5be6a33f-42df-47db-b1c0-e758fa14fdb9, ses=GridJobSessionImpl [ses=GridTaskSessionImpl

Comment: Can u please share a example of how this is achieved.

Comment: I still have a confusion of how will be the tables be accessed by cache???

Comment: Please take a look on this example - https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/store/auto/CacheAutoStoreExample.java